# Property Notification when Binding to Class Not Properties

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, binding, properties

I have a window that contains different functional areas of an account.  The details, roles, type, contracts...ect.  The window's DataContext is set to the 'AccountViewModel'.  Inside the AccountViewModel, there are properties one of them being 'Account' which contains the details.  I need for the user to be able to update these details.  How can I notifiy the properties to call my Update() code when they are changed?

Here is what I have

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtAccountNumber" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Account.AccountNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

```vb
Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    DataContext = AccountViewModel
End Sub

Class AccountViewModel
    Public Property Account As Account
        Get
            Return _account
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Account)
            _account = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class Account
    Private _accountNumber As String

    <DisplayName("Account Number")> _
    Public Property AccountNumber As String
        Get
            Return _accountNumber
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _accountNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle the `PropertyChanged` event of your object (attach a handler in the setter for example) and call your update method in the handler.

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction, thanks! For others that come upon this I added the following line when setting _account in Sub New() of the AccountViewModel class: AddHandler _account.PropertyChanged, AddressOf OnAccountPropertyChanged